# I want footer show in the bottom page

Tags: html, css, sass

When the user goes at the end of the page with the scrool, there he can see the footer. the footer must appear only at the end of bottom when the user go at the end. My code work when there are a lot of components in the page, so the footer does what I want. The problem is when the page has a little component the footer appears in this way:
[image]

My CSS are :

```css
html{
    min-height: 100% !important
    position: relative !important
}

#footer{
    background-color: #30373d
    width: 100%
    position: relative
    height: auto
}
```

```html
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Anyone can help m

Comment: The code you shared nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a wrapper around your content and give it a `min-height:100vh;` (or whatever height suits your actual layout) property like below.

If you want the footer to always appear at the bottom of the page, set it to `positon:absolute;`

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

footer {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  very little content
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working on the footer, work on the content. Given that your footer has a fixed dimension you can ensure the body content will always take at least the portion of the empty screen minus the footer size. For example you could specify your content min-height like this:

```
.content {
 min-height: calc(100vh - footerDimension)
}
```